Bios does not boot and ignores key press
I changed my UEFI saettings to legacy mode and booted on a usb drive with ubuntu, errasing all windows OS, now that I want to go back to windows I cant because the BIOS doesnt appear.
I would like to access my BIOS on my laptop(acer v5) but when i try to, by pressing F2, i hear a sound like a bip of computer understing the key pressed but passes it and goes to ubuntu desktop, ignoring the key pressed.
